# Conditional insert query (Row count validation). (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, insert, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a query that will count and compare the number of rows of two tables on two different databases. If they are equal then a record will be inserted into another table as 'Pass', else it will result in a 'Fail'.
I haven't been able to find any answers through google searches... Here is my query that isn't working:

```
select
case when
((select count(1) from db1.transaction) = (select count(1) from db2.transaction))
then
insert into db3.validation (test_result) values ('pass')
else
insert into db3.validation (test_result) values ('fail')
end;
```

Comment: You can't do an insert in a select. Seperate it. Use a procedure as shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by reversing the order.  Do a single `insert` with a `select` choosing the value:

```
insert into db3.validation(test_result)
    select (case when t1.cnt1 = t2.cnt2 then 'pass' else 'fail' end)
    from (select count(1) as cnt1 from db1.transaction) t1 cross join
         (select count(1) as cnt2 from db2.transaction) t2;
```

Note that I moved the subqueries from the `case` to a `from` clause, simply because I find them easier to read this way.  You can keep them in the `case` if you prefer.